# doc2vec inaccurate cosine similarity

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I have trained doc2vec model on 4 million records. I want to find most similar sentence to a new sentence i put in from my data but i am getting very bad results.

sample of data:

```
Xolo Era (Black, 8 GB)(1 GB RAM).
Sugar C6 (White, 16 GB)(2 GB RAM).
Celkon Star 4G+ (Black & Dark Blue, 4 GB)(512 MB RAM).
Panasonic Eluga I2 (Metallic Grey, 16 GB)(2 GB RAM).
Itel IT 5311(Champagne Gold).
Itel A44 Pro (Champagne, 16 GB)(2 GB RAM).
Nokia 2 (Pewter/ Black, 8 GB)(1 GB RAM).
InFocus Snap 4 (Midnight Black, 64 GB)(4 GB RAM).
Panasonic P91 (Black, 16 GB)(1 GB RAM).
```

Before passing this data i have done preprocessing which includes
1) Stop words removal.
2) special character and numeric value removal.
3) lowercase the data. 
I have also performed the same steps in testing process.

code which i used for training :

```
sentences=doc2vec.TaggedLineDocument('training_data.csv') # i have used TaggedLineDocument which can generate label or tags for my data

max_epochs = 100
vec_size = 100
alpha = 0.025

model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=vec_size,
                alpha=alpha, 
                min_alpha=0.00025,
                dm =1,
                min_count=1)
model.build_vocab(sentences)
model.train(sentences, epochs=100, total_examples=model.corpus_count)
model.save('My_model.doc2vec')
```

well i am new to gensim and doc2vec so i have followed an example for training my model so please correct me if i have used wrong parameters.

on testing side

```
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load('My_model.doc2vec')
test = 'nokia pewter black gb gb ram'.split()
new_vector = model.infer_vector(test)
similar = model.docvecs.most_similar([new_vector]) 
print(similar) # It returns index of sentence and similarity score
```

for testing i have passed same sentences which are present in training data but model does not give related documents as similar document,for example i got "**lootmela tempered glass guard for micromax canvas juice**" as a most similar sentence to **"nokia pewter black gb gb ram"** this sentence with 0.80 as a similarity score.

```
So my questions to you: 
1) Do i need to reconsider parameters for model training?
2) Training process is correct?
3) How to build more accurate model for similarity?
4) Apart from doc2vec what will be your suggestion for similarity (keeping in mind i have very large data so training and testing time should not be much longer)
```

Please forgive if question formatting is not good.

Comment: That's not natural language so natural language methods wont really help much. Maybe if you train on technical texts only or something but I suppose you would have to do something different. Maybe use some embedding coupled to an objective (price, ratings, etc.) .

Comment: @meow Thank you for your suggestion, But i only have product names, I don't have price or ratings. Do you recommend to use some different techniques than doc2vec or word2vec?

Comment: yes I would try different approaches. I think it will be really difficult to embed those products in a completely unsupervised manner. You could for example try to create a set of features out of the products and use those as vector representation of the product. E.g. encode the device type (e.g. smartphone, camera etc.), instructions per/ s *  #cores (for cpu), flops for gpu, price, ram, etc.. This requires some clever crafting of features but is much more likely to succeed.

Answer (score 13):

`Doc2Vec` will have a harder time with shorter texts – and it appears your texts may only be 5-10 tokens.

Your texts also don't appear to be natural-language sentences - but rather product names. Whether `Doc2Vec`/`Word2Vec`-like analyses will do anything useful with such text fragments that *don't* have the same sort of co-occurrence diversity as natural spoken/written language will depend on the characteristics of the data. I'm not sure it would, but it ight – only trying/tweaking it will tell.

But, it's not clear what your desired results should be. What kinds of product-names *should* be returned as most-similar? Same brand? Same color? (If either of those, you could use a much simpler model than `Doc2Vec` training.) Same specs, including memory? (If so, you wouldn't want to throw away numeric info – instead you might want to canonicalize it into single tokens that are meaningful at the word-by-word level that affects `Doc2Vec`, such as turning "64 GB" into "64gb" or "2 GB RAM" into "2gbram".)

As this isn't regular natural language text, you likely have a very small constrained vocabulary - perhaps a few thousand tokens, rather than the tens-to-hundreds-of-thousands in normal language. And, each token may only appear in a small number of examples (a single producer's product line), and absolutely never appear with closely-related terms from similar competitive products (because product names *don't* mix proprietary names from competitors.) These factors will also present a challenge for this sort of algorithm – which needs many varied overlapping uses of words, and many words with fine-shades of meaning, to gradually nudge vectors into useful arrangements. A small vocabulary may require use of a much-smaller model (lower `vector_size`) to avoid overfitting. If you had a dataset which hinted which products people consider comparable – either mentioned in same reviews, or searched-for by same people, or bought by same-people – you might want to create extra synthetic text examples which include those multiple products in the same text – so that the algorithm has a chance of learning such relationships.

Much `Doc2Vec`/`Word2Vec` work doesn't bother with removing stop-words, and may retain punctuation as standalone words.

You should show examples of what is actually in your "training_data.csv" file, to see what the algorithm is actually working with. Note that `TaggedLineDocument` wouldn't handle a real comma-separate-values file correctly - it's expecting just one text per line, already whitespace-delimited. (Any commas would be left in-place, perhaps attached to field tokens.)

Lowering `min_count` to 1 can often worsen results, because such rare tokens (with only 1 or a few occurrences) don't get good vectors, but if there are a lot of them in aggregate (which there are in normal texts but might not be here) can serve as training noise degrading other vectors.

You don't need to change `min_alpha`, and in general should only tinker with defaults if you're sure what they mean and have a rigorous, repeatable scoring process for testing whether changes are improving results or not. (In the case of achieving a good similarity measure, such a score might be a set of pairs of items that *should* be more-similar than some third item. For each algorithm/parameters you try, how many such pairs get properly discovered as "more similar" than either item to the third?)

Inference, especially on short texts, may benefit from different parameters (such as more inference passes) – and the latest gensim release (3.5.0, July 2018) includes an important fix and adjustment of defaults for `infer_vector()`. So be sure to use that version, and test the improvement of supplying it a larger `epochs` value.

Overall, I'd suggest:

- being clear about what a good similarity result should be: with examples of most- and least-similar items
- use such examples to create a rigorous automated evaluation of model quality
- preprocess in a domain-sensitive way that preserves meaningful distinctions; try to get/create texts that don't silo brand-words into tiny single-product examples that hide potential cross-brand relationships
- don't change defaults unless you're sure it's helping
- enable logging at INFO level so you can see progress of algorithm and reporting of things like effective vocabulary

You still might not get great results depending on what your real 'similarity' goal is – product names aren't the same sort of natural language `Doc2Vec` works best on.

Another baseline to consider is just treating each product-name as a 'bag-of-words' which gives rise to a one-hot vector of which words (from the full vocabulary) are in it. The cosine-similarity of these one-hot vectors (perhaps with extra term weighting) would be a simple measure and at least capture things like putting all 'black' items somewhat nearer each other, or all 'nokia' items, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. 1)  By most similar means, suppose i pass "Samsung galaxy 4 gb ram, black, 64 gb internal memory" then it should return "Samsung note 4 gb ram, white " or  "Nokia 6T 3 gb ram, rose gold", it doesn't matter which brand it is unless and until most similar document is mobile phone. 2) I have not tried any other algorithm except cosine similarity using TfidfVectorizer() but as my data set is huge it is taking alot of time to compute similarity. 3) as you suggest there are some simple techniques, would you please name any of them so i can try them on my side?

Comment: Your example is still not clear, because the only tokens shared between "Samsung galaxy 4 gb ram, black, 64 gb internal memory" and "Nokia 6T 3 gb ram, rose gold" are "gb ram" – and it seems almost every product will have those words. So if these are, in fact, similar, it requires other knowledge you're not supplying to the algorithm. It knows nothing but what you tell it. Now, if they were both mentioned in the same review, or appeared in the same list-of-products browsed/bought by the same person, that'd be a data-driven hint of similarity.

Comment: No pure Word2Vec/Doc2Vec technique will learn that "3GB-RAM" and "4GB-RAM" are similar from just your current data/preprocessing - bc numbers are opaque tokens, & the two will *never* appear in the same text, & learning relative-relationships at the very least requires many slightly-varying examples that reflect natural usage (as in real language). EG, if some discussions have "2GB-RAM" & "4GB-RAM", but others "4GB-RAM" & "8GB-RAM", but few have "2GB-RAM" & "8GB-RAM", it might learn 2 & 4 are close, and 4 & 8 are close, but 2 & 8 farther. But you current data/preprocessing gives it no chance.

Comment: Representing each item as a "bag-of-words", with a large-dimensionality 'sparse' one-hot-vector, as mentioned above, is a baseline you should try. But it will only detect similarities that are somewhat like counts-of-same-words. EG: your two Samsung examples have 4 tokens in common – `samsung` `4` `gb` `ram` – in common so would have a score like 4, while the Nokia only has 2 tokens in common – `gb` `ram` – so it'd have a score like 2. (Cosine-similarity or weightings by relative term frequencies/importances make things more subtle but it's still roughly "how many shared words".)

Comment: In contrast to that 'sparse' approach, Doc2Vec/etc create 'dense' vectors that *might*, if all goes well, help find patterns-of-relationships with smaller representations. But as mentioned above, there may not be enough variety/vocabulary/subtlety-of-cooccurence-contexts in your current data for Doc2Vec/etc to work on just this data. You might have more luck hand-tuning a model of the items, using your domain knowledge about specs, or other not-yet-shown data about comparable.s